# Add json object as child object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have JSON object

`{a : 'vala' , b:'valb' , childval : { x : 'valx'} } another object as {c: 'valc'}`

I would like to add these two objects as

`{a : 'vala' , b:'valb' , childval : { x : 'valx'} ,  {c: 'valc'} }`

Any pointers on how to add another object.

Comment: Is the first object actually JSON or a JavaScript object? The syntax you posted isn't valid JSON. Also, for `childval`, do you want to combine all keys into a single object or create an array of objects? Pointers - consider `Object.prototype.keys` or `Object.prototype.entries`.

Comment: `{a : 'vala' , b:'valb' , childval : { x : 'valx'} ,  {c: 'valc'} }` is not a valid syntax, do you mean `{a : 'vala' , b:'valb' , childval : { x : 'valx', c: 'valc' } }` ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I was not thinking about valid JSON. No wonder I was struggling to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I would do below if I imagine well your typo:

```
const foo = { a: 'vala', b: 'valb', childval : { x : 'valx' } };
const bar = { c: 'valc' };

foo.childval = { ...foo.childval, ...bar };
```

[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is neat for these situations

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
let obj1 = {a : 'vala' , b:'valb' , childval : { x : 'valx'} }
let obj2 = {c: 'valc'};

Object.assign(obj1.childval, obj2);
console.log(obj1);
```